# Sorting posts by custom field value

Tags: sort

I am trying to sort posts by their custom field value, which is a date in this format:

9 August 2012, 7:18 am

```
        'orderby'  => 'meta_value', 
        'meta_key' => 'wprss_item_date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
```

Do I need to do some conversion before that can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date should be stored in descending units, like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` for MySQL to be able to sort on the field.

See the [MySQL docs for Date, Datetime, and Timestamp data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).